# UWP pivot items style

Tags: xaml, xamarin, uwp, styles

How can i set two diferent Background for the Pivot Items, for example blue for "All" and red for "NotAll".

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"">    
    <PivotItem Header="All" x:Name="All">
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllList}}"
            SelectionMode="None">            
        </ListView>
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem x:Name="NotAll" Header="Not All">
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NotAllList}}"
            SelectionMode="None">
        </ListView>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to set background color of the whole pivot item, you can set its `Background` property:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Pivot" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <PivotItem Background="Blue" ...>
        ...
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Background="Red" ...>
        ...
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Alternatively, if you want to change the color of the header texts, you can use complex property syntax and just set the headers to a custom control:

```
<PivotItem x:Name="NotAll">
    <PivotItem.Header>
        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="Not all" />
    </PivotItem.Header>
    ...
</PivotItem>
```